# Ignoring Command Line Arguments in Excel

Tags: excel, command-line, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to make Excel ignore certain command line arguments?  I am launching via a command similar to:

```
Excel "C:\Temp\TestingCLAs.xlsx" /e service=http://localhost:61023/api/PortlandDev/2/ReportSource?Order='100146309'^&Line='0010'
```

The service string gets read by some VBA in the Excel file and is used to update a query.  However, when I launch Excel the command line argument interpreter see's two things:

1. Open "C:\Temp\TestingCLASs.xlsx"
2. Open service=http://....

I would like the interpreter to ignore the second argument, however I get the following error when opening:

> "Sorry, we couldn't find
>   service=http://localhost:61023/api/PortlandDev/2/ReportSource?Order='100146309'&Line='0010'.xlsx.
>   Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I know this isn't due to the VBA within the excel file because it happens even when testing with a blank excel file.

I found this reference article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/ and tried to escape the URL with a '^' character but, got the same result.

Also looking at the error above, a .xlsx is tacked on to the end of the second URL above when it wasn't specified in the initial call.

Is there a way to make the command interpreter not try to execute the URL?

Any ideas are very much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it works but passing a "/p" switch makes it so that the command interpreter does not try to automatically open the URL.  For example, the following can be consumed by my internal VBA without the command interpreter trying to create a new workbook from the URL.

```
Excel "C:\Temp\Template.xlsm" /e /p http://localhost:61023/api/PortlandDev/2/ReportSource?Order='100142574'&Line='0010'
```